# MainWindow ViewModel Reference from child views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This must be a silly question, but i can't find the answer. I have in my application a MainWindow with Viewmodel and childviews with corresponding viewmodels. I need to execute from child viewmodel a command defined on mainWindow ViewModel. I read that i need to use IoC and pass a reference of mainWindow ViewModel when create child view, but i don't know how!
On Child viewmodel Constructor i have this:

```
private readonly Main_ViewModel _mainVM;
public VM_ListadoClientes(Main_ViewModel MainVM)
    {
        _mainVM = MainVM;
    }
```

In the child view code behind i have this:

```
private VM_ListadoClientes viewModel = new VM_ListadoClientes(???);

    public ViewClientes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (s, e) => { this.DataContext = this.viewModel; };  
    }
```

So how do i get a reference to mainWindow viewmodel to pass in "???" parameter?

Also: do this break mvvm pattern? because child views are aware of mainwindow viewmodel existance.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I try this as EventAggregator class:

```
class EventAggregator
{
    public static void BroadCast(string message)            
    {
        if (OnMessageTransmitted != null)
            OnMessageTransmitted(message);
    }

    public static Action<string> OnMessageTransmitted;        
}
```

But i don't like the idea that is static, wich mean so is generic to all the application. Maybe i can make it local to a specific viewModel, but how do i subscribe child views to this event? Thanks

Comment: Create overloaded constructor of `ViewClientes` accepting viewModel as parameter. Ideally you should use some Mediator pattern OR EventAggregator so that both ViewModels remains loosely coupled.

Comment: Thank you? Can you give a basic example of a EventAggregator? See my update please! thanks!

Comment: Why you are creating `EventAggregator`? PRISM already have it defined. Refer to the example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample), [here](http://www.gonetdotnet.info/posts/wpf-articles/wpf-module-communication) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I consider messaging, event aggregators, etc as hacks and they will make your application very unmanagable. Why not use a solid solution? I recommend to use [Catel](http://catelproject.com/), and will try to give you a few reasons why.

1) It provides a [CommandManager](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Application-wide+commands) class where you can have application-wide commands registered with input gestures. This allows you to bind in xaml like this:

```
<Button Command="{catel:CommandManagerBinding File.Exit}" />
```

Then you can implement this command wherever you want and it will be passed to the right VM for you via a service.

2) Has a solid foundation to handle [nested user controls](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Introduction+to+the+nested+user+controls+problem) with separate view models.

3) Simply provides everything you will need in your application when using MVVM and XAML.